# Change status based on checkbox value rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes(which is for status of a record) in a page, I need to update the status of records while a button is clicked

```
<% collection.each do |staff| %>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" id="staff-<%= role.id %>">
 <input class="filled-in chk-col-indigo" type="checkbox" id="staffStatus- 
    <%=staff.id %>">
 <label class="labelValue" for="staffStatus-<%= staff.id %>">
<% end%>
```

when the submit button is clicked I just take all the checkbox based on checked status,

```
$(document).on 'click', '#StatusUpdateButton', ->
     inactive = []
     active = []
     $.each $(".staff__active:not(:checked)"), ->         
     inactive.push($(this).val())
     $.each $(".staff__active:checked"), ->
     active.push($(this).val())
```

In controller,

```
def update_role_status
             Staff.where('id IN (?)', params[:active]).update_all(active: true)
             Staff.where('id IN (?)', params[:inactive]).update_all(active: false)
        end
```

I am updating the status, But i want to do it with better option, Is that okay to  send all the checkbox status or will that be good to send only changed check boxes, I am in confusion to take the better option, Any suggession

Answer (score 0):

Without further information about your schema/models, the solution looks ok. I would just move the logic to the Model:

```
class Staff
  # ...
  def self.activate_all(ids)
    where(id: ids).update_all(active: true)
  end

  def self.deactivate_all(ids)
    where(id: ids).update_all(active: true)
  end
end

# controller
Staff.activate_all(params[:active])
Staff.deactivate_all(params[: inactive])
```

Another option is to use a nested form: https://coderwall.com/p/qwx3qa/nested-form-and-rails-4

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Is that good to send all the checkbox values at each time when the user submitting the changes, Or do I have to handle to have changed ids ( 0 to 1 and 1 to 0) while submitting form

Comment: If you use the nested form approach you would have to worry about handling the changed ids. The way you implemented you have to handle that by JS like you did or you could create a form and POST the data (then you wouldn't have to add JS)